# How to loop through a child of an AngularJS scope element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying out some Angular and I can't seem to get my head around `$scope` objects.

I don't seem to be able to easily loop through a scope objects child. I have a `match` object, which has `players` where I want to loop through to get their points.

```
app.controller('PlayController', function($scope, Points, Matches, $routeParams, $location){
  var id = $routeParams.id;
  $scope.match = Matches.get({id: id});

  angular.forEach($scope.match.players, function(value, key) {
      console.log(value);
      console.log("test");
  });
});
```

Nothing is returned here, no value or test and I'm sure $scope.match has 3 players in there.

Anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are doing a server side call in `Matches.get()`. An **A**JAX request is asynchronous so you will never get the results immediately after the code execution. So change you code like this:

```
var id = $routeParams.id;
$scope.match = Matches.get({id: id}, function(data) {   // Callback when your server responded the data
    console.log(data);

    angular.forEach($scope.match.players, function(value, key) {
       console.log(value);
       console.log("test");
    });
});
```

Comment: Legend! It seems I got so stuck with working with angular that I forgot something as basic as an AJAX call...

Comment: Sure, it happens :-) We are here to help.